# Plotting function that returns complex values using pyplot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I found this image on Facebook and wanted to plot it, as I thought it will be a good opportunity to learn something new.

[image: love formula]
<sub>(source: [akamaihd.net](https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/482615_550821728272176_1584451064_n.jpg))</sub>

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.special
import pylab

x = np.linspace( -1.0, 1.0, 200 )
y = np.sqrt(  1-np.square(np.complex64(x) ) ) + np.complex64( scipy.special.cbrt( np.square( x ) ) )
pylab.plot( np.complex64( x ), y )
pylab.show()
```

The Output:

[image: IMG]

I am unable to obtain the plot as given in the figure. In order to plot, I reordered the formula into `y = f(x)` form and translated it into the code above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y, x = np.ogrid[-1:2:100j, -1:1:100j]
plt.contour(x.ravel(), y.ravel(), x**2 + (y-((x**2)**(1.0/3)))**2, [1])
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

You can play with the aspect-ratio to make the curve a bit more heart-like:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
y, x = np.ogrid[-1.5:2:1000j, -2:2:1000j]
plt.contour(x.ravel(), y.ravel(), x**2 + (y-((x**2)**(1.0/3)))**2, [1])
ax.set_aspect(0.75) 
plt.show()
```

[image]